# How to create a quick windows .exe file which does nothing and doesn't close by itself?

Tags: windows

For example, I want to create a Potatoes.exe file. I don't need it to do anything else, just to be there opened. I don't want it to close by itself.

Comment: why you want worthless utility which take resources and do nothing?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair basically I have an app called Discord which detects games by reading active .exe files. If there's for example a "Minecraft.exe", it will say "Playing Minecraft". So it's expected to show the name of the game whenever you run it, something that doesn't happen for Minecraft. I decided to just create my own .exe file then to explore this further and and Discord indeed shows the name when running the fake Minecraft.exe. The whole problem with Minecraft not using an .exe in the first place is obvious, as it is a game made using java. I was just curious.

Comment: This is necro, but the correct answer is using the nop_continue exe from here: https://github.com/myfreeer/nop/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a batch file (by opening Notepad and saving as the file with `.bat` extension)

```
@echo off
pause > nul
```

and converting it to executable file (`.exe`) with one of the thrid-party batch to executable file type convertors [[1]](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) [[2]](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) [[3]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bat-to-exe/).